# CSS layout in vaadin : the label and button are not comming in line

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am creating label and one button in vaadinn
And when i put these componants on Css Layout the content are comming like

- label
- button

but i want this is in 
-label -buttom

does any one know the solution what css should be applied for that?

best Regards
Arvind

Comment: Labels are 100% width be default, so probably this is what is happening. Try with setting the label width to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions for your problem. You can add `StyleName` to your `CssLayout` like this :

```
myCssLayout.setStyleName("my-layout");
```

and then add this to your css file:

```
.my-layout .v-label{
  float:left;
}
```

Or, and this is the right way to resolve your problem, you can use `HorizontalLayout` instead of `CssLayout`. It will allow you to put your components in one line.

```
HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
layout.addComponent(mybutton);
layout.addcomponent(mylabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

for the components like you have label and button

```
label.setWidth(Sizeable.SIZE_UNDEFINED, 0);
```

then you also have to make this css changes for that component

```
u-component-label{
    display:inline-block;
}
```